# NSIGHT compute: SOL SM versus Roofline

Tags: cuda, nsight-compute, roofline

I ran cuda-11.2 [nsight-compute](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/index.html) on my cuda kernel.

It reports that SOL SM is at 79.44% which I interpret as being pretty close to maximum. SOL L1 is at 48.38%

When I examine the [Roofline](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/index.html#roofline) chart, I see that my measured result is very far away from peak performance.

**Achieved**: *4.7 GFlop/s.*

**Peak at roofline**: *93 GFlop/s or so.*

I also see ALU pipe utilization at 80+%

So, if the ALU pipe is fully utilized, why is the achieved performance so much lower, according to the roofline chart?

[image: profile result]

Note that this is on a RTX 3070, which peaks for single precision at 17.6 TFlop/s:
[image: peak]

**UPDATE**

I think I figured out what is going on here... @robert-crovella put me on the right track showing that ALU are integer ops, thus not included. And that those are not the only operations not included!

**Roofline charts only show fp32 and fp64 operations and not fp16 operations.**

My code works with half-precision floats, making the Roofline chart not applicable for my code, I suspect.

Comment: I think you need to check the magnitude of the numbers in your question because they don't look even remotely realistic

Comment: @talonmies Ah, thank you. Indeed: I read the values wrong, off by a factor 1000. It was GFlops, not TFlops. Still my observation stands: The SoL says: close to max. The RoofLine says: not even remotely close to max.

Answer (score 4):

> So, if the ALU pipe is fully utilized, why is the achieved performance so much lower, according to the roofline chart?

Because the ALU pipe [has nothing to do with floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413176/interpreting-compute-workload-analysis-in-nsight-compute/61431557#61431557) and the roofline chart is essentially only about floating point.

As indicated in the answer I linked, the ALU pipe handles:

> most integer instructions, bit manipulation instructions, and logic instructions

It's quite possible that this pipe utilization is a factor that is limiting the performance of your kernel, and as a result of that, you are running at a lower FLOPs/s rate/throughput than what might be otherwise achievable, floating-point wise (i.e. the roofline).

The items that are (FP32/FP64) floating-point related are fma, fmaheavy, fp32, and potentially Tensor.  These are all at around 40% or below active, so you're not maxing out any of those pipes.

Comment: Thanks. Good points. However, 40% of peak is still far away from what the roofline is showing, where there is a much larger delta: a factor 20 for the current arithmetic density. And a much much larger factor if we look at the absolute peak performance possible.